# Maui Picker popup width and item clipping on Mac Catalyst

Tags: maui, mac-catalyst

On Mac Catalyst the Maui `Picker` control is implemented as a swiftui-style picker in a popup. Item labels that are longer that about 18 characters (on my non-retina mac) are right-clipped and have an ellipsis appended.

Is there a way to increase the width of the popup so that longer text items can be displayed? Or to disable the label clipping? Or some other way to display longer item labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By viewing the source code of [PickerHandler in the Mac Catalyst](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Core/src/Handlers/Picker/PickerHandler.iOS.cs#:%7E:text=var%20frame%20%3D%20new%20RectangleF(0%2C%20paddingTitle%2C%20269%2C%20pickerHeight)%3B) part of Maui, you can see:

`var frame = new RectangleF(0, paddingTitle, 269, pickerHeight);`

The source code sets the width of the control to 269. You can refer to the source code to customize the Picker control to change the width. For customizing controls in Maui, you can refer to the official document: [Create a custom control using handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/create?view=net-maui-7.0)

Comment: Thank you. I was only dimly aware of handlers, but having done some reading I think this is the way to solve the problem.